# How to dump all properties content of an anytype

Tags: swift, core-data

let's say I have some MO-classes like this one

```
class MonthGroup: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var displayOrder: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var isdeleted: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var remarks: String?
    @NSManaged var requireUpdate: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var uid: String
    @NSManaged var exerRel: NSSet

}
```

And I need a function to iterate through any given Object's properties and return their value (if exist! - I don't want BAD ACCESS runtime errors)

Something like

```
func dumpObject(anyObject:AnyObject) {
    println("\(anyObject.className) has the following values:")

    for property in anyObject.properties {
        println("\(property.name) value: \(property.value)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `NSManagedObject` has a [`NSEntityDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/). Which has various attributes to inspect the entity. E.g. `- propertiesByName`, `– relationshipsByName` and `- propertiesByName`. These are dictionaries with the name of the attribute or relationship as key and a `NSAttributeDescription` and/or `NSRelationshipDescription` object as value.

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    func dumpProperties() {
        for (key, _) in entity.propertiesByName as [String : AnyObject] {
            println("\"\(key)\": \(valueForKey(key))")
        }
    }
}
```